# Event Receiver subscribing to Custom Document Library Template

Tags: document-library, content-type, event-receivers, 2016, list-template

I have a List Template `DocLibTemplate` with `FeatureId : {00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101}`. I am trying to have a event receiver subscribe to all libraries of this type. This is the code I have for the `Elements.xml` file for the event receiver.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiver1ItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SharePointProject7.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

From my undesrtanding specifying that `ListTemplateId="101"` means the event handler will subscribe to Document Libraries. Is there a way to have it subscribe to only Document Libraries that use the `DocLibTemplate` either through the TemplateID of the template or the FeatureID, or can I create a new ContentType and have the list subscribe to that?

Edit :
I found the xml file for the list template by downloading the list template stp file and unarchiving that. This had the manifest.xml file which contains the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it through `ListTemplateID` on the event receiver and use the number you specified in the `Type` attribute in your list template declaration.

So for instance if your list template looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
    <ListTemplate
        Name="My Custom List Template"
        Type="1234"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="360"
        DisplayName="My Custom List Template"
        Description="A template for lists of type My Custom Type."/>
</Elements>
```

Then in your event receiver, use:

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="1234">
```

Comment: Since I have already created the ListTemplate `DocLibTemplate` where do I find this information for it?

Comment: It should be in the Elements file for the list template.  Can you post that XML?

Comment: How do I access the elements file?

Comment: How did you create the list template?  I assumed you created it in Visual Studio since you have a Feature ID associated with the template.

Comment: No I created a list and saved it as a template.

Comment: Ah.  Well, you might have to get Powershell involved to dig around and find the template definition.  Not sure, but it also might be possible to find it using Designer?  Or SharePoint Manager.  Something that will get you "behind the scenes", so to speak.  Also keep in mind that, at leas in VS, the `Type` attribute of a custom list definition defaults to 10000 (I think?), and you will need to change it to something more specific and custom.  Again, that will probably involve Powershell.

Comment: I will try and find the xml file and from that I think I can get it working.